# How to add a generic SwiftUI view to another view?

Tags: ios, generics, swiftui

When trying to use a generic type to init/add a view to another SwiftUI view, I get the error `Type 'T' has no member 'init'`. How can this be solved?

I guess the problem is, that `View` is just a protocol which only requires a `body` property and nothing more. But what type could be used instead?

**Simple Example:**

Trying to use `TrippleView<T: View>` which should create/show three views of type `T`. Adding views (`RedRectView` or `BlueCircleView`) is no problem. Passing these views as generic parameter fails:

```
struct SomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TrippleView<RedRectView>()
        TrippleView<BlueCircleView>()
    }
}

struct TrippleView<T: View>: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Does NOT work: Type 'T' has no member 'init'
            T()
            T()
            T()
            
            // Works fine
            // RedRectView()
            // BlueCircleView()
            // RedRectView()
        }
    }
}

struct RedRectView: View {...}
struct BlueCircleView: View {...}
```

**EDIT:**

The `TrippleView` is of course just an example. I would like to use the generic view just as any other generic type: To a common base "type" in different scenarios.

For example two versions of a list view which use a generic `CellView` to display the same data in two different styles / layouts.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Something that automatically creates three instances of a given view and arranges them, or something else?

Comment: I have edited the question to point this out.

Comment: How do you expect `T()` to work if all the compiler knows is that `T` conforms to `View`, and the `View` protocol doesn't declare that initializer? You'd need to create your own protocol that conforms to `View` and declare the initializer you want in it, then you can use that as the requirement for `T` and you would know your views can be initialized that way.

Comment: I'm not sure how your example would work - without a specific initializer, you'd be unable to display any data. It seems like you're trying to reinvent view builders? If you really want to go ahead with this you need to declare an additional protocol with whatever initializer you expect your conforming views to have - you can't just say "its a View" and leave it at that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a ViewBuilder inside your struct to initialize the view. Here's an example,

### Struct that takes in generic view and returns a view.

```
struct TripleView<T: View>: View {
// simple example that takes in one parameter.
var someView: T

init(@ViewBuilder someView: () -> T) {
    self.someView = someView()
}

var body: some View {
    // You can modify your viewes here. 
    someView
        .foregroundColor(.red)
    someView
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
    someView
        .foregroundColor(.green)
    }
}
```

Or you can take in multiple parameters

```
struct TripleViewsWithParam<T1: View, T2: View, T3: View>: View {
// you can take as many parameters as you want.
var someView1: T1
var someView2: T2
var someView3: T3

init(@ViewBuilder someView1: () -> T1, @ViewBuilder someView2: () -> T2, @ViewBuilder someView3: () -> T3) {
    self.someView1 = someView1()
    self.someView2 = someView2()
    self.someView3 = someView3()
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        someView1
        someView2
        someView3
    }
}
}
```

### Calling the struct in your main view

```
struct SomeView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        TripleView {
            Text("Triple View Example")
        }
        TripleViewsWithParam(
            someView1: {
                Text("View 1")
            }, someView2: {
                Text("View 2")
            }, someView3: {
                Text("View 3")
            }
        )
    }

}
}
```

[image: The result]

Comment: Thanks for the great example + explanation. This makes things much clearer.

Comment: I came across a (possible) limitation of this solution and added a new question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73571940/777861

Answer (score 1):

**Jan 2024 UPDATE**

There is now a property wrapper for the view builder. So you do not need to write the initializer.

```
 @ViewBuilder let viewContent: ViewContent
```

*EXAMPLE*

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExampleView<ViewContent: View>: View {

@ViewBuilder let content: ViewContent

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
            
            content
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ExampleView {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}
```

*USAGE*

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ExampleApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ExampleView {
                Text("Hello World")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great. But I get an error in the PreviewProvider: `Generic parameter 'ViewContent' could not be inferred. Explicitly specify the generic arguments to fix this issue`. How to fix it?

Comment: Updated my answer, hope that helps.